# How can i use a single entity for multiple intents in Dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to access a single entity value for multiple intent's in dialogflow (API.AI). I tried adding same value in another entity but it doesn't work either may be i would have missed some thing.

for example like i have an entity containing value like 20 now this value is being used for extracting some details of the user using an intent lets say A. Now i want the same entity value to update some user data which is being done by intent B.The problem here is on using the entity at B intent the intent of A is being initialising. I want that when B intent is being going through the entity value should work according to that respective intent itself but that's not happening.
is it clear now?

Comment: Can you update your question to provide examples and/or screen shots of what you're trying to do and what isn't working?

Comment: you can check out now!

Comment: Slightly more clear. It sounds like you have two Intents, but one intent is always being triggered, even if you expect the other Intent to trigger. Correct? If so, can you update the question to include screen captures of both Intents? There are several reasons this might happen, but seeing both Intents will make it more clear what the cause is.

Comment: yes and that happens due to the usage of same entity in bot the intent's yes sure wait ill post the snaps of both the intent's